# Floating Boat 3D Physics Rotation from Rudder (no water resistance)

Tags: unity, c#

I have been able to simulate a floating boat very simply by attaching a script called `Boat.cs` to a ship model with a `Rigidbody`; the Drag and Angular Drag are set to `2`, and the mass to `15`, and the Rigidbody uses gravity.

```
  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
  public class Boat : MonoBehaviour {
     public static float waterLevel = 16.6f;
     public float floatThreshhold = 2.0f;
     public float waterDensity = 0.125f;
     public float downForce = 0.5f;

     float forceFactor;
     Vector3 floatForce;
     public Transform pointOfBuyancy;

      void FixedUpdate () {

        forceFactor = 1.0f - ((transform.position.y - waterLevel) / floatThreshhold);
        if(forceFactor > 0.0f)
        {
           floatForce = -Physics.gravity * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass * (forceFactor - GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.y * waterDensity);
           floatForce += new Vector3(0.0f, -downForce * GetComponent<Rigidbody>().mass, 0.0f);
           GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForceAtPosition(floatForce, pointOfBuyancy.position);
        }
     }
  }
```

the `Transform` named `pointOfBuyancy` is an empty placed above the ship model. This is where the floating force is applied, acting as a pendulum to stabilize the ship. This script works very well, and doesn't require changes.

The control script is called `SimpleBoatController.cs`, and is as follows:

```
  // Denis Labrecque, copy of #02 Boat Movement - How to make a Boat Controller - Unity 3D on YouTube

  using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  [RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
  [RequireComponent(typeof(Boat))]
  public class SimpleBoatController : MonoBehaviour {

     public float movementThreshold = 0.2f;
     public float turnThreshold = 0.2f;
     public float maxSpeed = 30.0f;

     public Transform pointOfEngine;

     Rigidbody rigidbody;
     Transform centerOfMassTransform;
     float waterDynamicFactor;
     float verticalInput;
     float movementFactor;
     float horizontalInput;
     float steerFactor;

     public float CurrentSpeed { get; private set; }

      // Use this for initialization
      void Start () {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
      }

      // Update is called once per frame
      void Update () {
        // Assign properties
        CurrentSpeed = rigidbody.velocity.x;

        Move();
      }

     void Move()
     {
        // Receive player input
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        // Calculate factors
        movementFactor = Mathf.Lerp(movementFactor, verticalInput, Time.deltaTime * movementThreshold);
        steerFactor = Mathf.Lerp(steerFactor, horizontalInput, Time.deltaTime * turnThreshold);

        // Move forwards
        rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition(new Vector3(movementFactor * rigidbody.mass * maxSpeed, 0, 0), pointOfEngine.position);

        // Turn
        // https://forum.unity.com/threads/rigidbody-lookat-torque.146625/
        // rigidbody.AddTorque(Vector3.Cross(transform.forward, rigidbody.velocity), ForceMode.FORCE);
        rigidbody.AddTorque(0, transform.position.y * CurrentSpeed * 25f * horizontalInput, 0); // Rotate
        rigidbody.AddTorque(Vector3.Cross(rigidbody.velocity, transform.forward), ForceMode.Force); // Align relative to direction
        Debug.Log("Turning of " + horizontalInput);
     }
  }
```

This script requires an additional empty at the location of the center of mass of the ship, called `pointOfEngine` in the code, where the ship is pushed forwards. This works very well.

My difficulty is in the **move** method, when it comes to applying rotation.

Because the flotation script does not apply any angular drag, the boat rotates without turning in the direction of rotation. It makes a flat spin and wobbles like over jellow -- which looks good, but just doesn't allow controlling the boat.

How can I make the boat travel in an arc, and not just back and forth while making a flat spin?

I have searched various physics answers about rotation and wind resistance, but these don't apply to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following for the boat control:

```
public Vector3 COM;
[Space (15)]
public float speed = 1.0f;
public float steerSpeed = 1.0f;
public float movementThresold = 10.0f;

Transform m_COM;
float verticalInput;
float movementFactor;
float horizontalInput;
float steerFactor;

public GameObject Rudder;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    Balance ();
    Movement ();
    Steer ();
}

void Balance () {
    if (!m_COM) {
        m_COM = new GameObject ("COM").transform;
        m_COM.SetParent (transform);
    }

    m_COM.position = COM;
    GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().centerOfMass = m_COM.position;
}

void Movement () {
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");
    movementFactor = Mathf.Lerp (movementFactor, verticalInput, Time.deltaTime / movementThresold);
    transform.Translate (0.0f, 0.0f, movementFactor * speed);
}

void Steer () {
    horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    steerFactor = Mathf.Lerp (steerFactor, horizontalInput * verticalInput, Time.deltaTime / movementThresold);
    transform.Rotate (0.0f, steerFactor * steerSpeed, 0.0f);

    // To move the physical rudder wheel on the deck
    Rudder.transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, steerFactor * steerSpeed * 5f);
}
```

Comment: This answer would be even better if it included a description of why this solves OP's problem, to help a reader develop an intuition about the strategy you're using rather than just copying your code.

Comment: I'm using physics, so I'll have to check whether `transform.Rotate` and `transform.Translate` are really the way to go. Thank you for your feedback; I'll look into it once I have time.